# Appending a java.sql.Date in an SQLite JDBC query

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I've been using PreparedStatements throughout my entire database where you can use `setDate(index, data)`, however would it work to use a Date object like this?

`"SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN " + date + " AND " + otherDate`

Are there any online tools that I can use to test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe this function will work:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN " + date + " AND " + otherDate
```

Since your trying to concatenate two `Date` objects with several `String` literals.  You would need to use a `DateFormatter` to turn the `Date` into a `String`.

You should stick with the `PreparedStatement`s and avoid creating SQL statements by concatenating Strings/Values.  The `PreparedStatement` is going to offer you some protection against `sql injection`, while the String concatenation method is going to expose you to the risk of sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

The best would be to format your date in a database recognizable format, when you append directly to the `String`, the date's `toString()` would be called, and I doubt that the database would support that syntax, you will be better off doing something like this:

```
final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String s = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '" 
    + formatter.format(date) + "' AND " + formatter.format(otherDate) + "'";
```

Also, as kevin mentioned, rather stick to `PreparedStatement`s, as this offers you more protection.